# How do I implement plugins in Laravel / PHP

Tags: laravel, plugins, modular-design

I'm trying to make a plugin system that could integrate with existing functions / components in an eCommerce Laravel project.

By integrating with existing functions / components, I mean to have the ability to add on more payment methods by interacting with the API and not requiring the user to register events or service providers.

I'm also trying to make it so that the existing functions / components can interact with the plugin to pull information or functions like "Auto Login to X" and "Change DirectAdmin password."

These functions are similar to [WHMCS](https://www.whmcs.com/) which is a billing platform for hosting companies.

I currently do not know where to start to create such a module system that will interact with each other.

(I'm willing to give clarifications if I sound a bit confusing)

Comment: There's https://packagist.org/packages/nwidart/laravel-modules . Alternatively, you can create your own composer packages and load them using service providers. If you want to oversimplify things, you can also just use raw PHP classes in some `app/modules` directory.

Comment: @Flame I see. Is there a way my application would be able to start interacting with modules without having to code it?

Like I would define the functions in the modules and the Laravel app would recognize it then use the functions/events from the module.

I want to make the modules work with the existing application instead of creating a entirely new component that is separate.

Also, if I were to pull functions like "Reset application password" and statistics from the plugin, would a service provider work? I don't want to use the wrong functions from Laravel.